# Android online API documentation incomplete?

Tags: android, api, documentation

In the Android online API documentation, lots of methods seem to be undocumented, e.g.,

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setProgress(int)

I don't think it's a matter of the methods being inherited.

Clearly this can't be the case, I'm sure millions of developers would be up-in-arms otherwise, so can somebody explain why the documentation isn't here?

Michael

Comment: To be fair, the functionality of most (all?) of the undocumented methods in your link example is fairly obvious...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can somebody explain why the documentation isn't here?

Because nobody wrote it.

You are welcome to examine [the source code to the class in question](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ProgressDialog.java) and [contribute a patch to AOSP](http://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-patch.html) with suitable JavaDocs for any gaps.

Or, you are welcome to [file an issue](http://b.android.com) for any methods that are missing documentation, particularly those whose usage is not intuitively obvious. There is a "Developer Documentation" issue template that will help to route the issue to the appropriate people.